MacOS X11 window not launching through Terminal, but launches through XQuartz terminal
I installed XQuartz using brew, and it seems that X11 forwarding only works when I launch a terminal through XQuartz and use ssh -X on it. It doesn't work when I run ssh -X on my Terminal app (XQuartz is still running in the background).

Check if your $DISPLAY environment variable is set in the XQuartz terminal and NOT set in the Mac terminal. If so, set it manually and try again. If that works, set it thru one of the “dot” files that manage your shell/login settings.

Instead of the xquartz version from brew you should try to download and install XQuartz-2.8.5.pkg directly from the website xquartz.org.
For me starting any X11 app from terminal or iTerm automatically launches XQuartz.app and in the terminal $DISPLAY was already set to an unusual vale that was surely set by the pkg installer (I do not use xquartz from brew). It kinda looks like some launchd script or app sets this variable. Maybe be the brew version did no do this?
$ echo $DISPLAY
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.NzZKy3HHcG/org.xquartz:0

I find a launchd plist under:  /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.xquartz.privileged_startx.plist
that starts:
/opt/X11/libexec/privileged_startx -d /opt/X11/etc/X11/xinit/privileged_startx.d

And there is also another script under: /Library/LaunchAgents/org.xquartz.startx.plist
that seems to take care to set DISPLAY.
As you see this privileg extension and DISPLAY set mechanism is installed in /opt/X11/ but not in /opt/homebrew/ so it must be from the pkg installer. Maybe something went wrong with brew installation.

I ran into exactly the same situation today, as described by Waitsnake:
Have installed xquartz (via homebrew) but the $DISPLAY environment variable was still unset.
I prefer not to install the XQuartz application from their website directly, as I like to use brew.
So when ssh -Y'ing, got "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set".
What fixed this, was to reboot macOS (Sequoia). After a reboot, the $DISPLAY environment variable was set and X11 forwarding works.
For example:
~$: echo $DISPLAY
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.by00lZqTxO/org.xquartz:0


Note: The path shown above is a UNIX socket.
